# Why isn't this Postgres function correct?

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_user(_name TEXT, _pass TEXT, _iconid INTEGER)
RETURNS user_info
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
DECLARE
    _newid INTEGER;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users(name, password, iconid) VALUES (_name, crypt(_pass, gen_salt('bf')), _iconid);
    SELECT _newid = currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users', 'id'));


    SELECT u.id, u.name, u.rating, t.name, i.path, i.name FROM users u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN usertypes t ON t.id = u.typeid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN usericons i ON i.id = u.iconid
    WHERE u.id = _newid;
END
$$;
```

I get:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTEGER"
Line 6:    _newid INTEGER;
                  ^
```

I am sure there's something I'm missing but it's been really frustrating so far because the tools are substandard compared to almost EVERY other major db - mysql, sql server, oracle, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't this Postgres function correct?

Because it doesn't contain valid SQL.  It appears to contain plpgsql code.  Try changing the language:

```
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Now the function creates, but I get this error when executing:  `select * from public.create_user('DerpDerp5678', 'password', 1);
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function create_user(text,text,integer) line 6 at SQL statement`

Comment: Marking this as the answer, but - doesn't matter at this point.  I am sick of wrestling with crappy tools.  Back to mySQL where mysterious, corner-case tasks like EDITING A FUNCTION aren't hidden away in dusty corners.

Comment: You need a separate question for that error.  Although it will probably be a duplicate.

Comment: The error message of PostgreSQL is correct, informative and exhausting. You have done a query using SELECT, but not said what to do with the result. What else but an error message can you expect in this situation? But feel free to go back to some crappy database system.